# MS Access VBA .additem to listbox subscript out of range error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I get an error when trying to add values to a list box based on a selection in a combo box. The filter(?) I added for the recordset doesn't tell the lngRows to only use those items after the filter is applied vs all in the table I think is part of my issue. It errors out when adding, it puts the values in the box then errors due to adding blanks. Is there a way to fix this?

```
Private Sub Combo5_AfterUpdate()
Set lb = Me.lbSA.Object

    Dim varSelection() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    lngRows = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblSA").RecordCount
    varSelection = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT PROJ_ID,ShipArea FROM tblSA WHERE PROJ_ID = '" & Me.Combo5.Column(1) & "'").GetRows(lngRows)

    For i = 0 To lngRows - 1
        Me.lbSA.AddItem (varSelection(0, i)) 'error is here
        Me.lbSA.Column(1, i) = varSelection(1, i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for array or listbox objects:

```
Private Sub Combo5_AfterUpdate()
    Dim varSelection As Recordset
    Set varSelection = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT PROJ_ID, ShipArea FROM tblSA WHERE PROJ_ID = '" & Me.Combo5.Column(1) & "'")
    While Not varSelection.EOF
        Me.lbSA.AddItem varSelection(0), 0
        varSelection.MoveNext
    Wend
End Sub
```

Or just set RowSource property. Make sure RowSourceType property is set to Table/Query.

```
Private Sub Combo5_AfterUpdate()
    Me.lbSA.RowSource = "SELECT PROJ_ID, ShipArea FROM tblSA WHERE PROJ_ID = '" & Me.Combo5.Column(1) & "'")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and I appreciate your time
the first option gives me an invalid use of property error  at varselection
the second one is a syntax error.
any other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in my code. Was missing the `Set` for the recordset. See revised answer. Both work for me.

Comment: Thank you for the assist 
I used the second example as the first one did not error but there were no values in the list box.
Private Sub Combo5_AfterUpdate()
 Dim SQL As String
 SQL = "SELECT PROJ_ID, ShipArea FROM tblSA WHERE PROJ_ID = '" & Me.Combo5.Column(1) & "'"
 Me.lbSa.RowSource = SQL
End Sub